# What is "[0]#011train-merror:0.17074#011validation-merror:0.1664" error when running xgb_model.fit() in AWS Sagemaker?

Tags: python, xgboost, amazon-sagemaker

I'm running through the official sagemaker tutorial [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/ex1-train-model.html).

And although training completes, I'm getting errors like below periodically during training, `xgb_model.fit(inputs=data_channels,  logs=True)`.

I have no experience with xgboost or sagemaker at this point.

```
[0]#011train-merror:0.17074#011validation-merror:0.1664
```

**Full logs:**

```
2019-05-08 17:04:32 Starting - Starting the training job...
2019-05-08 17:04:33 Starting - Launching requested ML instances.........
2019-05-08 17:06:10 Starting - Preparing the instances for training......
2019-05-08 17:07:06 Downloading - Downloading input data...
2019-05-08 17:07:50 Training - Training image download completed. Training in progress.
Arguments: train
[2019-05-08:17:07:51:INFO] Running standalone xgboost training.
[2019-05-08:17:07:51:INFO] File size need to be processed in the node: 1122.95mb. Available memory size in the node: 152390.7mb
[2019-05-08:17:07:51:INFO] Determined delimiter of CSV input is ','
[17:07:51] S3DistributionType set as FullyReplicated
[17:07:55] 50000x784 matrix with 39200000 entries loaded from /opt/ml/input/data/train?format=csv&label_column=0&delimiter=,
[2019-05-08:17:07:55:INFO] Determined delimiter of CSV input is ','
[17:07:55] S3DistributionType set as FullyReplicated
[17:07:56] 10000x784 matrix with 7840000 entries loaded from /opt/ml/input/data/validation?format=csv&label_column=0&delimiter=,
[17:07:56] src/tree/updater_prune.cc:74: tree pruning end, 1 roots, 48 extra nodes, 6 pruned nodes, max_depth=5
[17:07:57] src/tree/updater_prune.cc:74: tree pruning end, 1 roots, 50 extra nodes, 8 pruned nodes, max_depth=5
[17:07:57] src/tree/updater_prune.cc:74: tree pruning end, 1 roots, 46 extra nodes, 6 pruned nodes, max_depth=5
[17:07:57] src/tree/updater_prune.cc:74: tree pruning end, 1 roots, 54 extra nodes, 4 pruned nodes, max_depth=5
[17:07:57] src/tree/updater_prune.cc:74: tree pruning end, 1 roots, 58 extra nodes, 4 pruned nodes, max_depth=5
[17:07:57] src/tree/updater_prune.cc:74: tree pruning end, 1 roots, 38 extra nodes, 8 pruned nodes, max_depth=5
[17:07:57] src/tree/updater_prune.cc:74: tree pruning end, 1 roots, 38 extra nodes, 2 pruned nodes, max_depth=5
[17:07:57] src/tree/updater_prune.cc:74: tree pruning end, 1 roots, 48 extra nodes, 2 pruned nodes, max_depth=5
[17:07:57] src/tree/updater_prune.cc:74: tree pruning end, 1 roots, 58 extra nodes, 2 pruned nodes, max_depth=5
[17:07:57] src/tree/updater_prune.cc:74: tree pruning end, 1 roots, 60 extra nodes, 0 pruned nodes, max_depth=5
[0]#011train-merror:0.17074#011validation-merror:0.1664
[17:07:57] src/tree/updater_prune.cc:74: tree pruning end, 1 roots, 52 extra nodes, 6 pruned nodes, max_depth=5
[17:07:57] src/tree/updater_prune.cc:74: tree pruning end, 1 roots, 42 extra nodes, 14 pruned nodes, max_depth=5
[17:07:57] src/tree/updater_prune.cc:74: tree pruning end, 1 roots, 52 extra nodes, 2 pruned nodes, max_depth=5
[17:07:57] src/tree/updater_prune.cc:74: tree pruning end, 1 roots, 62 extra nodes, 0 pruned nodes, max_depth=5
[17:07:58] src/tree/updater_prune.cc:74: tree pruning end, 1 roots, 54 extra nodes, 8 pruned nodes, max_depth=5
[17:07:58] src/tree/updater_prune.cc:74: tree pruning end, 1 roots, 44 extra nodes, 6 pruned nodes, max_depth=5
[17:07:58] src/tree/updater_prune.cc:74: tree pruning end, 1 roots, 44 extra nodes, 12 pruned nodes, max_depth=5
[17:07:58] src/tree/updater_prune.cc:74: tree pruning end, 1 roots, 48 extra nodes, 4 pruned nodes, max_depth=5
[17:07:58] src/tree/updater_prune.cc:74: tree pruning end, 1 roots, 60 extra nodes, 0 pruned nodes, max_depth=5
[17:07:58] src/tree/updater_prune.cc:74: tree pruning end, 1 roots, 46 extra nodes, 12 pruned nodes, max_depth=5
[1]#011train-merror:0.12624#011validation-merror:0.1273
[17:07:58] src/tree/updater_prune.cc:74: tree pruning end, 1 roots, 48 extra nodes, 10 pruned nodes, max_depth=5
[17:07:58] src/tree/updater_prune.cc:74: tree pruning end, 1 roots, 36 extra nodes, 20 pruned nodes, max_depth=5
[17:07:58] src/tree/updater_prune.cc:74: tree pruning end, 1 roots, 54 extra nodes, 4 pruned nodes, max_depth=5
[17:07:58] src/tree/updater_prune.cc:74: tree pruning end, 1 roots, 60 extra nodes, 2 pruned nodes, max_depth=5
[17:07:58] src/tree/updater_prune.cc:74: tree pruning end, 1 roots, 58 extra nodes, 4 pruned nodes, max_depth=5
[17:07:58] src/tree/updater_prune.cc:74: tree pruning end, 1 roots, 48 extra nodes, 0 pruned nodes, max_depth=5
[17:07:58] src/tree/updater_prune.cc:74: tree pruning end, 1 roots, 48 extra nodes, 6 pruned nodes, max_depth=5
[17:07:59] src/tree/updater_prune.cc:74: tree pruning end, 1 roots, 50 extra nodes, 4 pruned nodes, max_depth=5
[17:07:59] src/tree/updater_prune.cc:74: tree pruning end, 1 roots, 60 extra nodes, 0 pruned nodes, max_depth=5
[17:07:59] src/tree/updater_prune.cc:74: tree pruning end, 1 roots, 56 extra nodes, 2 pruned nodes, max_depth=5
[2]#011train-merror:0.11272#011validation-merror:0.1143
[17:07:59] src/tree/updater_prune.cc:74: tree pruning end, 1 roots, 50 extra nodes, 8 pruned nodes, max_depth=5
[17:07:59] src/tree/updater_prune.cc:74: tree pruning end, 1 roots, 36 extra nodes, 20 pruned nodes, max_depth=5
[17:07:59] src/tree/updater_prune.cc:74: tree pruning end, 1 roots, 50 extra nodes, 6 pruned nodes, max_depth=5
[17:07:59] src/tree/updater_prune.cc:74: tree pruning end, 1 roots, 60 extra nodes, 2 pruned nodes, max_depth=5
[17:07:59] src/tree/updater_prune.cc:74: tree pruning end, 1 roots, 50 extra nodes, 8 pruned nodes, max_depth=5
[17:07:59] src/tree/updater_prune.cc:74: tree pruning end, 1 roots, 52 extra nodes, 6 pruned nodes, max_depth=5
[17:07:59] src/tree/updater_prune.cc:74: tree pruning end, 1 roots, 50 extra nodes, 6 pruned nodes, max_depth=5
[17:07:59] src/tree/updater_prune.cc:74: tree pruning end, 1 roots, 52 extra nodes, 4 pruned nodes, max_depth=5
[17:07:59] src/tree/updater_prune.cc:74: tree pruning end, 1 roots, 60 extra nodes, 2 pruned nodes, max_depth=5
[17:07:59] src/tree/updater_prune.cc:74: tree pruning end, 1 roots, 44 extra nodes, 12 pruned nodes, max_depth=5
[3]#011train-merror:0.10072#011validation-merror:0.1052
[17:08:00] src/tree/updater_prune.cc:74: tree pruning end, 1 roots, 48 extra nodes, 12 pruned nodes, max_depth=5
[17:08:00] src/tree/updater_prune.cc:74: tree pruning end, 1 roots, 34 extra nodes, 22 pruned nodes, max_depth=5
[17:08:00] src/tree/updater_prune.cc:74: tree pruning end, 1 roots, 54 extra nodes, 2 pruned nodes, max_depth=5
[17:08:00] src/tree/updater_prune.cc:74: tree pruning end, 1 roots, 56 extra nodes, 4 pruned nodes, max_depth=5
[17:08:00] src/tree/updater_prune.cc:74: tree pruning end, 1 roots, 56 extra nodes, 6 pruned nodes, max_depth=5
[17:08:00] src/tree/updater_prune.cc:74: tree pruning end, 1 roots, 54 extra nodes, 6 pruned nodes, max_depth=5
[17:08:00] src/tree/updater_prune.cc:74: tree pruning end, 1 roots, 56 extra nodes, 2 pruned nodes, max_depth=5
[17:08:00] src/tree/updater_prune.cc:74: tree pruning end, 1 roots, 52 extra nodes, 2 pruned nodes, max_depth=5
[17:08:00] src/tree/updater_prune.cc:74: tree pruning end, 1 roots, 58 extra nodes, 2 pruned nodes, max_depth=5
[17:08:00] src/tree/updater_prune.cc:74: tree pruning end, 1 roots, 52 extra nodes, 8 pruned nodes, max_depth=5
[4]#011train-merror:0.09216#011validation-merror:0.097
[17:08:00] src/tree/updater_prune.cc:74: tree pruning end, 1 roots, 46 extra nodes, 12 pruned nodes, max_depth=5
[17:08:00] src/tree/updater_prune.cc:74: tree pruning end, 1 roots, 30 extra nodes, 22 pruned nodes, max_depth=5
[17:08:00] src/tree/updater_prune.cc:74: tree pruning end, 1 roots, 58 extra nodes, 4 pruned nodes, max_depth=5
[17:08:00] src/tree/updater_prune.cc:74: tree pruning end, 1 roots, 58 extra nodes, 2 pruned nodes, max_depth=5
[17:08:01] src/tree/updater_prune.cc:74: tree pruning end, 1 roots, 52 extra nodes, 10 pruned nodes, max_depth=5
[17:08:01] src/tree/updater_prune.cc:74: tree pruning end, 1 roots, 52 extra nodes, 10 pruned nodes, max_depth=5
[17:08:01] src/tree/updater_prune.cc:74: tree pruning end, 1 roots, 56 extra nodes, 6 pruned nodes, max_depth=5
[17:08:01] src/tree/updater_prune.cc:74: tree pruning end, 1 roots, 40 extra nodes, 14 pruned nodes, max_depth=5
[17:08:01] src/tree/updater_prune.cc:74: tree pruning end, 1 roots, 54 extra nodes, 6 pruned nodes, max_depth=5
[17:08:01] src/tree/updater_prune.cc:74: tree pruning end, 1 roots, 46 extra nodes, 8 pruned nodes, max_depth=5
[5]#011train-merror:0.08544#011validation-merror:0.0904
[17:08:01] src/tree/updater_prune.cc:74: tree pruning end, 1 roots, 46 extra nodes, 12 pruned nodes, max_depth=5
[17:08:01] src/tree/updater_prune.cc:74: tree pruning end, 1 roots, 36 extra nodes, 14 pruned nodes, max_depth=5
[17:08:01] src/tree/updater_prune.cc:74: tree pruning end, 1 roots, 60 extra nodes, 2 pruned nodes, max_depth=5
[17:08:01] src/tree/updater_prune.cc:74: tree pruning end, 1 roots, 60 extra nodes, 0 pruned nodes, max_depth=5
[17:08:01] src/tree/updater_prune.cc:74: tree pruning end, 1 roots, 54 extra nodes, 8 pruned nodes, max_depth=5
[17:08:01] src/tree/updater_prune.cc:74: tree pruning end, 1 roots, 54 extra nodes, 2 pruned nodes, max_depth=5

[17:08:01] src/tree/updater_prune.cc:74: tree pruning end, 1 roots, 56 extra nodes, 4 pruned nodes, max_depth=5
[17:08:01] src/tree/updater_prune.cc:74: tree pruning end, 1 roots, 36 extra nodes, 16 pruned nodes, max_depth=5
[17:08:02] src/tree/updater_prune.cc:74: tree pruning end, 1 roots, 60 extra nodes, 2 pruned nodes, max_depth=5
[17:08:02] src/tree/updater_prune.cc:74: tree pruning end, 1 roots, 42 extra nodes, 12 pruned nodes, max_depth=5
[6]#011train-merror:0.08064#011validation-merror:0.0864
[17:08:02] src/tree/updater_prune.cc:74: tree pruning end, 1 roots, 50 extra nodes, 8 pruned nodes, max_depth=5
[17:08:02] src/tree/updater_prune.cc:74: tree pruning end, 1 roots, 38 extra nodes, 14 pruned nodes, max_depth=5
[17:08:02] src/tree/updater_prune.cc:74: tree pruning end, 1 roots, 58 extra nodes, 4 pruned nodes, max_depth=5
[17:08:02] src/tree/updater_prune.cc:74: tree pruning end, 1 roots, 58 extra nodes, 2 pruned nodes, max_depth=5
[17:08:02] src/tree/updater_prune.cc:74: tree pruning end, 1 roots, 46 extra nodes, 8 pruned nodes, max_depth=5
[17:08:02] src/tree/updater_prune.cc:74: tree pruning end, 1 roots, 50 extra nodes, 6 pruned nodes, max_depth=5
[17:08:02] src/tree/updater_prune.cc:74: tree pruning end, 1 roots, 54 extra nodes, 6 pruned nodes, max_depth=5
[17:08:02] src/tree/updater_prune.cc:74: tree pruning end, 1 roots, 40 extra nodes, 14 pruned nodes, max_depth=5
[17:08:02] src/tree/updater_prune.cc:74: tree pruning end, 1 roots, 60 extra nodes, 2 pruned nodes, max_depth=5
[17:08:02] src/tree/updater_prune.cc:74: tree pruning end, 1 roots, 50 extra nodes, 4 pruned nodes, max_depth=5
[7]#011train-merror:0.0769#011validation-merror:0.0821
[17:08:02] src/tree/updater_prune.cc:74: tree pruning end, 1 roots, 46 extra nodes, 16 pruned nodes, max_depth=5
[17:08:02] src/tree/updater_prune.cc:74: tree pruning end, 1 roots, 38 extra nodes, 20 pruned nodes, max_depth=5
[17:08:03] src/tree/updater_prune.cc:74: tree pruning end, 1 roots, 52 extra nodes, 2 pruned nodes, max_depth=5
[17:08:03] src/tree/updater_prune.cc:74: tree pruning end, 1 roots, 54 extra nodes, 4 pruned nodes, max_depth=5
[17:08:03] src/tree/updater_prune.cc:74: tree pruning end, 1 roots, 44 extra nodes, 10 pruned nodes, max_depth=5
[17:08:03] src/tree/updater_prune.cc:74: tree pruning end, 1 roots, 52 extra nodes, 2 pruned nodes, max_depth=5
[17:08:03] src/tree/updater_prune.cc:74: tree pruning end, 1 roots, 54 extra nodes, 6 pruned nodes, max_depth=5
[17:08:03] src/tree/updater_prune.cc:74: tree pruning end, 1 roots, 38 extra nodes, 2 pruned nodes, max_depth=5
[17:08:03] src/tree/updater_prune.cc:74: tree pruning end, 1 roots, 58 extra nodes, 4 pruned nodes, max_depth=5
[17:08:03] src/tree/updater_prune.cc:74: tree pruning end, 1 roots, 48 extra nodes, 8 pruned nodes, max_depth=5
[8]#011train-merror:0.0731#011validation-merror:0.0809
[17:08:03] src/tree/updater_prune.cc:74: tree pruning end, 1 roots, 50 extra nodes, 12 pruned nodes, max_depth=5
[17:08:03] src/tree/updater_prune.cc:74: tree pruning end, 1 roots, 32 extra nodes, 24 pruned nodes, max_depth=5
[17:08:03] src/tree/updater_prune.cc:74: tree pruning end, 1 roots, 56 extra nodes, 2 pruned nodes, max_depth=5
[17:08:03] src/tree/updater_prune.cc:74: tree pruning end, 1 roots, 50 extra nodes, 10 pruned nodes, max_depth=5
[17:08:03] src/tree/updater_prune.cc:74: tree pruning end, 1 roots, 50 extra nodes, 8 pruned nodes, max_depth=5
[17:08:03] src/tree/updater_prune.cc:74: tree pruning end, 1 roots, 48 extra nodes, 8 pruned nodes, max_depth=5
[17:08:04] src/tree/updater_prune.cc:74: tree pruning end, 1 roots, 52 extra nodes, 6 pruned nodes, max_depth=5
[17:08:04] src/tree/updater_prune.cc:74: tree pruning end, 1 roots, 38 extra nodes, 14 pruned nodes, max_depth=5
[17:08:04] src/tree/updater_prune.cc:74: tree pruning end, 1 roots, 60 extra nodes, 2 pruned nodes, max_depth=5
[17:08:04] src/tree/updater_prune.cc:74: tree pruning end, 1 roots, 50 extra nodes, 6 pruned nodes, max_depth=5
[9]#011train-merror:0.06942#011validation-merror:0.0773

2019-05-08 17:08:12 Uploading - Uploading generated training model
2019-05-08 17:08:12 Completed - Training job completed
Billable seconds: 66
```

Is this something I should be concerned about?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No need to worry. These are not errors in your code. These are info messages that are calculating the error of the model on the training data (train-error) and on the validation data (validation-error), and these values should get smaller as the training progress.

In time, these values will be more meaningful for you. You will be able to compare different algorithms and hyper-parameters based on which is the smaller error, or you will be able to see that your model is overfitting, when the error values of the training is very different from the validation error.